# Writing a query to find a entry in a nested object

Tags: json, mongodb-query, nosql

So I'm looking for a way to check if an e-mail is taken in my DB.

The data is nested and the object looks like this:

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "59c50b9190c4fe1c54c8ca85"
  },
  "scriptData": {
    "email": "email1@address.com",
    "age": "10",
    "lang": "undefined",
    "avatar": "undefined"
  }
}
```

I'm using findOne() to find the data in a collection and the problem is I don't know how to write the query properly.

I want to look for for the email value in there. Tried some query like:

{"email" : "email1@address.com"} found anything

{ "scriptData" : {"email" : "email1@address.com"} } nothing too

{ "scriptData" : {"email" : "email1@address.com" , "age": "10", "lang": "undefined","lang": "undefined"} } Found it!

So I had to write the whole nested data in order to find it. Since users can bypass the register by changing a field like age, I cant use that query.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is your question, and how is this related to jquery?

Comment: Change the title capitlization to conform to convention.

Comment: idk stackoverflow tagged it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to description as mentioned in above question please try executing following query into MongoDB shell.

```
db.collection.find({
    'scriptData.email': 'email1@address.com'
})
```

Comment: wrote the query that way and it worked properly. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can access it using javascript. But your question doesn't make much sense, so I cannot give you a better answer.

```js
var smth = {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "59c50b9190c4fe1c54c8ca85"
  },
  "scriptData": {
    "email": "email1@address.com",
    "age": "10",
    "lang": "undefined",
    "avatar": "undefined"
  }
};

console.log(smth.scriptData.email);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well i have a DB and I load a collection likee.a

Comment: Idk if its related to jquery. Stackoverflow taged it automatically.

well i'm loading a colection using this 

var playerCollection = Spark.systemCollection("player");

then I search in that collection doing this:

var result = playerCollection.findOne( "The query data" );

so i need to find out how to write this query properly.